# From template parameter to constructor argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Does C++17 (or earlier but not c++20) allow this?

I need a type_traited conditional class, like a bitset with an internal 32 or 64 unsigned integer storage, depending if the template argument N is lesser then 32 or greater (please forget about more than 64 bits).

But the constraint is to finally implement two and only two classes for all possible cases. Next source code defines the problem using static and running time asserts:

Coliru link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d53a5b00bd828fb5

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct bitset32
{
    bitset32() : bits(0) { }
    bitset32(int _bits) : bits(_bits) { }

    const int bits;
    uint32_t value;
};

struct bitset64
{
    bitset64() : bits(0) { }
    bitset64(int _bits) : bits(_bits) { }
    
    const int bits;
    uint64_t value;
};

template <int N>
using bitset = std::conditional_t<(N<=32), bitset32, bitset64>;

int main ()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<bitset<1>, bitset<2>>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same<bitset<33>, bitset<34>>::value);
    static_assert(!std::is_same<bitset<1>, bitset<33>>::value);

    bitset<1> var1;
    bitset<15> var2;
    bitset<32> var3;
    bitset<64> var4;

    assert(var1.bits == 1);
    assert(var2.bits == 15);
    assert(var3.bits == 32);
    assert(var4.bits == 64);
}
```

Any solution is welcomend even if it changes the basic types and uses inheritance or whatever other mechanism necessary, but please, do not offer using a template function returning an object in the style of `template<int N> make_bitset { return Bitset<N>(N); }` because it is needed to implement variables using this constructo `Bitset<N> variable_name`.

Comment: Not possible. If `bitset<1>` and `bitset<15>` are the same type, you need to pass the value to the constructor. Which is not possible without... passing a value to the constructor.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I was wondering if in modern c++ the template can pass the argument to the constructor in a unnown way for me, but maybe you are right and it is just impossible

Comment: `std::is_same<bitset<1>, bitset<2>>::value` requires that `bitset<1>` and `bitset<2>` have the exact same most derived type, so the bit count can't be in the type.  And there's no info passed to the constructor, so the bit count _must_ be in the type. Can we relax the `is_same` check?

Comment: Also this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you hitting these requirements? You need to fix _that_

Comment: "But the constraint is to finally implement two and only two classes for all possible cases" WHY? "static_assert(std::is_same<bitset<1>, bitset<2>>::value)" WHY?

Comment: @Mooing Duck - Thank you for your comments. The "hard candy" in this problem is the 2 and only 2 class types constraint, so relaxing it would allow several ways to solving the problem: template spetialization, sfinae... but this BitSet class is a simplification of a bitset serialization library that aims to decode or encode thousands of datagrams per second. I would like to test if there is an improvement by using two classes in the hope of cache prediction boost while keeping current interface. This is why I need that BitSet<1> and BitSet<32> were the same class type.

Comment: @Pablo if you expect an optimization, why it must be `bitset<N> var`? a `constexpr` function `make_bitset` may be optimized as what you want (same type and `bits` is emplaced with `N`). what's the difference between `bitset<N> var` (you want `bits` to be set) and `bitset<N> var{N}`?

Comment: @RedFog - Not difference at all, it would be the easy way to proceed, but current interface is `bitset<N>` and I must to keep backward compatibility. The way you suggest is easily implemented with a macro to avoid the two N's definition.

Comment: @Pablo: What you ask for is not possible. [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc9b7b06e73455d9) is as close as you're going to get.

Comment: @RedFog: Not bad, here static polymorphism can solve the problem in the most reliable way considering stated constraints. Do you wish to make a formal answer insteas of comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new hypothesis, [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) based

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t>
struct BitSet;

template <>
struct BitSet<32u>
 {
   template <typename ... Ts>
   BitSet (Ts...) {}

   std::uint32_t value;
 };

template <>
struct BitSet<64u>
 {
   template <typename ... Ts>
   BitSet (Ts...) {}

   std::uint64_t value;
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
BitSet (Ts...) -> BitSet<(32 < sizeof...(Ts) ? 64u : 32u)>;


int main()
 {
   auto b1 = BitSet{1};
   auto b2 = BitSet{2};
   auto b3 = BitSet{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
                    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
                    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
                    30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39};
   auto b4 = BitSet{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
                    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
                    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
                    30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
                    40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49};

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(b1), decltype(b2)> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(b1), BitSet<32u>> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(b3), decltype(b4)> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(b3), BitSet<64u>> );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not what I am looking for. Maybe I have been unclear in my question. What i want is: A template BitSet class which accepts N bits as template arguments, and "generates" the same class type for all N between 1 and 32, and the same type class for all N between 33 and 64. With the same type class I ask for `std::is_same(BitSet<1>, BitSet<2>) = true`. Then, internal storage must be uint32 and uint64 depending of N, and finally and more difficult, template must be able to initialize `bits` member variable to N. Is this impossible in current C++?

Comment: @Pablo - Yes... I've misunderstood  your question. And for `std::is_same(BitSet<1>, BitSet<2>)`, no, isn't possible in current C++. You can simulate it with a `using`: `template <std::size_t ... Is> using BitSet = ClassBitSet<sizeof...(Is)>;` but from the list of integers, you maintain only the length of the pack.

Comment: Thank you again, yes i am afraid that is not possible. It is a pity because for me it will be very useful for fast protocol serialization: it would be friendly interface to use and very efficient due to cache prediction for being most time the same types.

Comment: @Pablo but what's wrong with a template class, two specializations as in my example, where the template parameter is "decided" through CTAD? You could get (I suppose) `std::is_same_v<decltype(BitSet(1)), decltype(BitSet(2))> == true` because (CTAD) `BitSet(1)` become `BitSet<32>(1)` and `BitSet(2)` become `BitSet<32>(2)`. But `BitSet(0, 1, ...., 87)` (87 arguments) become `BitSet<64>(0, 1, ...., 87)`.

Comment: @Pablo - I've changed the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There is nothing wrong with your advice, sorry because I did not really understand it because it is first time I heard over it, I would like to ask you if it would be possible to simplify one step further, and use N directly instead of `sizeof...`. I mean something like this: `template <typename std::size_t N> BitSet (N) -> BitSet<(32 < N) ? 64u : 32u)>;` (but compiling, this does not),

Comment: @Pablo - No, it's not possible in that way. CTAD permit to "deduce" (decide, in this case) the template parameters according the argument of the constructor (a fake constructor, when explicit (in this case)). I've said, in my explicit CTAD: if the number of parameters of the constructor (that is `sizeof...(Ts)`) is greater than `32u`, the template parameter is `64u`, otherwise is `32u`. But all depends from the number of the parameters of the constructor.

Comment: In your experience, do you think that something like "std::make_index_sequence" could solve this? I am trying but not able to work it out. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence

Comment: @Pablo - `std::make_index_sequence` is extremely useful. But I don't see a way to use it for your problem. But maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make `bitset32` and `bitset64` templates like

```
template <std::size_t BitsUsed>
struct bitset32
{
    bitset32() : bits(BitsUsed) { }
    bitset32(int _bits) : bits(_bits) { }

    const int bits;
    uint32_t value;
};

template <std::size_t BitsUsed>
struct bitset64
{
    bitset64() : bits(BitsUsed) { }
    bitset64(int _bits) : bits(_bits) { }
    
    const int bits;
    uint64_t value;
};
```

and now the default constructor will pull in the correct number of bits. Then you just need to modify your alias like

```
template <int N>
using bitset = std::conditional_t<(N<=32), bitset32<N>, bitset64<N>>;
```

and you get the behavior you are asking for.

This will not work if you want to store a `bitset<5>` in the same container as a `bitset<32>` though since different template instantiations create distinct type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not the behaviour I was looking for. The key of the question is to only implement 2 final classes, independtly of the number of bits in ranges [1, 32] and [33, 64]. I wonder if this is possible or not at all

Comment: @Pablo: No, it's 100% impossible given the constraints you laid out, as the number of bits must simultaneously be part of the type and also not part of the type.